# Perform delete while inner joining table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-delete

I want to delete an entry in my **PAGES** table. Upon deletion of it, it will cascade to **OBJECTS** table. No worries in here, it's working if I delete the entry by using simple `DELETE`. However, I need to specify some conditions:

**PAGES** table

```
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| page_id                  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| users_id                 | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| page_value               | varchar(20)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**OBJECTS** table

```
+----------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| objects_id                 | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| page_id                    | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| objects_name               | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| objects_avail              | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

If `objects_avail == "ALL"`, I must not include that entry in cascade delete. I came up with this SQL query but got an error:

```
$query = "
    DELETE FROM pages AS p 
    INNER JOIN objects AS o ON p.page_id = o.page_id 
    WHERE p.page_id = ? 
      AND p.users_id = ? 
      AND p.page_value = ? 
      AND o.objects_avail != ?";
```

The error thrown:

> ["42000",1064,"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'AS p INNER JOIN objects AS o ON p.page_id = o.page_id WHER'
>   at line 1"]

Example value for the PDO placeholders:

`$params = array(81,5,"main page","ALL");`

where all of this is valid and I'm sure this is not where the problem is.

I doubt or prettry sure I'm missing some in my query, any suggestions please?

Comment: try using this $query = "DELETE FROM 'pages' AS 'p' INNER JOIN objects AS o ON 'p'.'page_id' = 'o'.'page_id' WHERE 'p'.'page_id' = ? AND 'p'.'users_id' = ? AND 'p'.'page_value' = ? AND 'o'.'objects_avail'!= ?";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an inner join UPDATE or DELETE, you need to specify which of the tables you actually want to delete explicitly, or else the parser won't know what you mean. You can choose 1 or more tables to delete from. In your case, it makes sense to just delete p, the alias for pages.

```
DELETE p
FROM pages AS p
INNER JOIN objects AS o ON p.page_id = o.page_id
WHERE
    p.page_id = ? AND
    p.users_id = ? AND
    p.page_value = ? AND
    o.objects_avail != ?
```

The only line I changed was DELETE became DELETE p

Comment: Also, please note that this is MySQL-specific syntax, and may not carry over to other RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks for this, this got rid of the error. However, it does delete rows with `ALL` availability value which must not because I specified `!= "ALL"`.

Comment: Can you post your PHP code then? The query above is correct, it's just that your parameter is not getting passed in correctly.

Comment: I just figured out that MySQL won't let me preserved some entries due to ON DELETE CASCADE. If it thus, I shall removed then that feature, how can I adjust my query to delete manually on both tables?

Comment: If you want it to delete pages no matter what, you should use a Left Join. Inner Join means that if there is no corresponding object for a page, then it will not be selected, and therefore can't get deleted.